# How to copy a file from my local disk to remote applicatin in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

Let's say I have created XML file inside C:/path/MyFolder/MyFile.xml. I want to copy them to my remote account in a Unix machine. ~/Home/www.

I read the tutorial, no where I see where I can copy or move file from my local to the remote system.

Comment: This one http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix2.html

Comment: So many ways to do this.  Have you looked at FTP, SCP, NFS mounting, SMB/SAMBA, and my favourite, sshfs.  What flavour of unix (or linux) are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scp` is a good suggestion, but for beginners i recommend sftp with a graphical client, like winscp or filezilla.

http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

https://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

I would use scp to send files to remote machines. For example:

```
scp C:/path/MyFolder/MyFile.xml user@remoteBox:/home/www/MyFile.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this is scp (secure copy). A famous client ist putty.

Just google it ;) Of course, on the unix machine you must install a ssh-server (very often in the official repository).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ftp or scp.
Maybe, from a Windows host you can easily use filezilla to do so. It's a very intuitive program.